# Test works locally but fails in the CI, it looks like cypress removing some cookies after navigating off domain

Tags: cypress

everyone! My test runs without any problems locally, but fails on the auth2 after redirect in CI. As I think it's connected with losing cookies, because it works when I intercept the request of redirect and add such lines in code:

```
cy.getCookies().then((cookies) => {
              cy.intercept('*redirect.html*', (req) => {
                const cookiesToSend = ['machineid'];
                req.headers['Cookie'] = cookies
                  .filter(({ name }) => cookiesToSend.some((el) => el.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()))
                  .map((cookie) => cookie.name + '=' + cookie.value)
                  .join(';');
              })
            }
          );
```

Cypress version is 9.7.

Do you have any ideas why it can happen?